# Bundle the same values from one array together and calculate the value on another array based on the first array's bundled number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm probably doing a bad job explaining, but I made this picture to make it clearer https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKAYc.png

---

I basically have the months in one array: `8 8 8 8 9 9 10 10 10`

and the data in another: `2 3 3 1 8 3 4 2 4`

---

and I want the months to be just: `8 9 10`

and the values to be calculated according to that: `9 11 10`

---

also here is a link to the exact thing im working on https://jsfiddle.net/Lyzn3rum/

Comment: How are you calculating data?

Comment: You haven't provided enough details, nor have you provided any code. for example, we don't know the correlation between these two arrays. it sounds like you have datapoints for each month, and you need to sum the datapoints for each month, but there is hardly enough details for us to help you with that. add the necessary info and code examples of the arrays, then we can help you.

Comment: It's still a bit unclear to me how you calculate values from the second array. In your example it seems kind of clear how you get your first 9 and the 10 (2 + 3 + 3 + 1, 4 + 2 + 4) but not the second 9 (8 + 3?).

Comment: @JamesHamann oh yeah that was of course just a mistake i made, the idea however should be understandable despite my mistake

Comment: @r3wt sorry, i didn't expect you guys to need more info, I did link to the jsfiddle thought, was that not sufficient?

Comment: @lynxlead you typically would include some code that you have written in the problem, which would help further illuminate what you are trying to do. The JSFiddle should be a supplementary link. That said, I think I understand what you are going for and will try to help with an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: included the separate singleMonths array.

This answer would only work if a couple assumptions are made. I am assuming that:

1. The "month" array will always be sequential and in order
2. The "data" array indices will always correspond to an index in the month array

You can write this with a fancy array reduce method, but that might be a bit complex for a beginner. Instead, we can create some variables to track what month we are on, and then loop through the month array and sum up the corresponding data values:

```
const months = [7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10];
const data = [2, 3, 3, 1, 8, 3, 4, 2, 4];

var singleMonths = [months[0]];
var lastSeen = months[0];
var sum = 0;
var values = [];

for (let i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
  if (months[i] !== lastSeen) {
    singleMonths.push(months[i]);
    values.push(sum);
    sum = data[i];
    lastSeen = months[i];
  } else {
    sum += data[i];
  }
  
  if (i == months.length - 1) {
    values.push(sum);
  }
}

console.log(singleMonths);
console.log(values);
```

Comment: you're assumption is correct, and it was my mistake for not being clear enought sorry.
but i cant find the months on your solution, the data is fine though

Comment: Oh gotcha, well I can edit it to include months

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after but its not clear based on your question. you don't explain the correlation between `months` and `data` so i just assume the index of the month correlates to the index for the datapoint.

```
const months = '8 8 8 8 9 9 10 10 10'.split(' ').map(v=>parseInt(v,10));
const data = '2 3 3 1 8 3 4 2 4'.split(' ').map(v=>parseInt(v,10));
// assumes index for month correlates to index for data
const results = {};
months.forEach((v,i)=>{
    if( results[v]===undefined ) {
        results[v] = data[i];
    }else{
        results[v] += data[i];
    }
});

const monthsFiltered = Object.keys(results); // 8,9,10
const dataFiltered = Object.values(results); // 9,11,10
```

Comment: this is really good, with the only downside that if the months start again after a new year the numbers get counted to the "old months", lets say "1 3 8 8 9 9 1 1 3" I only get "1 3 8 9" instead of "1 3 8 9 1 3" you know?

Comment: You didn't specify that condition in your post, but regardless the accepted answer will work in that scenario

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#reduce` with an object to store the sum for each month.

```js
let arr = '8 8 8 8 9 9 10 10 10'.split(' ').map(Number),
    data = '2 3 3 1 8 3 4 2 4'.split(' ').map(Number);
const res = arr.reduce((acc,curr, idx)=>(acc[curr] = (acc[curr] || 0) + data[idx], acc), {});
console.log(Object.keys(res));//months
console.log(Object.values(res));//data
```

Comment: This is fantastic, the problem is if I have arr that goes "1 3 8 8 9 9 1 1 3" I only get "1 3 8 9" instead of "1 3 8 9 1 3" you know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

the code in a basic way, without using the built-in method of arrays.

```js
function bundler(monthArray, dataArray){
  const months = [];
  const datas = [];

  let currentMonth = monthArray[0];
  let dataSum = dataArray[0];
  
  months.push(currentMonth)
  
  for(let i = 1; i < dataArray.length; i++){
    const month = monthArray[i];
    const data = dataArray[i];
    
    if(currentMonth !== month){
      months.push(month);
      currentMonth = month;

      datas.push(dataSum)
      dataSum = data;
    }else{
      dataSum += data;
    }
  }
  
  datas.push(dataSum)

  return [months, datas]
}
```